# MessagePack formatter for Web API (not ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, msgpack

We are trying to implement **MessagePack** on our Web API. However I am having trouble finding a reliable up-to-date formatter. I found the **WebApiContrib.Formatting.MsgPack** formatter but the last update was in 2014 and when I try using it it throws "Method not found" exception.

I also looked at an [example here](https://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/boost-up-your-asp-net-web-api-with-messagepack/) but the code contains some method references that are no longer present in the nuget package.

There seems to be an updated ASP.NET Core library with a set of formatters but we are not looking to move to Core any time soon.

Does someone have a tip for a reliable formatter for MessagePack that would do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing custom Media Type Formatter is pretty easy task if you have all serialization/deserialization code. So if you can't find suitable solution, you could implement your own. Here is working sample:

```
public class MessagePackFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public MessagePackFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-msgpack"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        }
        if (writeStream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(writeStream));
        }

        MessagePackSerializer.NonGeneric.Serialize(type, writeStream, value, ContractlessStandardResolver.Instance);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
        }
        if (readStream == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(readStream));
        }

        var value = MessagePackSerializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(type, readStream, ContractlessStandardResolver.Instance);
        return Task.FromResult(value);
    }
}
```

As you see it's very thin and just invokes `MessagePackSerializer.NonGeneric` class for serialization/deserialization. I'd suggest starting using such simple formatter and if you encounter some problems with it for specific cases, just tune the code to fix the issues. You could also examine [existing implementation](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib.Core/tree/master/src/WebApiContrib.Core.Formatter.MessagePack) for .Net Core for handling some corner cases.